# invalid Firebase binding source with vuefire

Tags: firebase, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm starting with vue and firebase, but now I have this error when I show what I already have in my database.

main.js

```
import vueFire from 'vuefire';
import firebase from 'firebase';

Vue.use(vueFire);

let config = {


apiKey: "mykey",
  authDomain: "mydomain",
  databaseURL: "myurl",
  projectId: "my",
  storageBucket: "bucket",
  messagingSenderId: "number"
};

let application = firebase.initializeApp(config)
let db = application.database()
let notificationsdb = db.ref('notifications')

export { notificationsdb };
```

component.vue

```
import { notificationsdb } from '../main';
export default {

    name: 'Notifications',

    firebase: {
      notifi: notificationsdb
    },

    data() {
      return{
        newNoti: {
          name: '',
          text: ''
        },

      }
    },

    methods: {
      addNoti: function(){
        notificationsdb.push(this.newNoti);
        this.newNoti.name = '',
        this.newNoti.text = ''
        toastr.success('Notificación creada');
      },
      deleteNoti: function(noti){
        notificationsdb.child(noti['.key']).remove();
        toastr.success('Notificación eliminada');
      }
    }
  }
```

If I delete this line of code and save it and then put it back, I keep changes, it works. But if I press F5 it stops working

```
firebase: {
      notifi: notificationsdb
    },
```

and he sent me the following error

**[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "Error: VueFire: invalid Firebase binding source."**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm assuming you started your project with something like:

```
vue init webpack myProject
```

Basically what's happening is your component doesn't have access to the data from firebase the first time you load it. It takes some time for you to make an edit (time in which the server request is completing). Then when you press save, it triggers the HMR, and your site reloads with the data it's expecting.

Try making these changes (although you should move this config stuff into a separate file (like `firebaseDB.js` for example)):

```
// let db = application.database()
// let notificationsdb = db.ref('notifications')
// export { notificationsdb }
export default application.database()
```

Then in `component.vue`:

```
[...]
import db from '../firebaseDB'
[...]
firebase: {
  notifi: db.ref('notifications')    
},
[...]
```

You'll probably want to add a `loading` state var to this component, and so on. Good luck!